# Error trying to release upgrade to 22.04

Tags: 22.04

I want to update from Focal to Jammy.

I have gotten the error:

```
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.,
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
W:GPG error: https://cli.github.com/packages stable
InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059, 
E:The repository 'https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease' is not signed.
```

What do I do? Should I uninstall cli.github somehow?

Comment: Thank you.  What, exactly, does 'source' mean here?  I have lots of source code from friends, etc.  Does 'source' here mean a repository of code that is listed as a trusted repository?  Is there one, or more, of these lists?  Where is it or are they?

Comment: Thank you, Nmath! I'll try this and get back!